# More Strings - strstr

Tags: c, string

So I'm trying to make my own strstr function, with the following implemenation:

```
 char *mystrstr(char *haystack, char *needle);
   // find the first occurrence of string needle
   // in string haystack
   // identical to strstr in <string.h>
   // running time O(mystrlen(needle)*mystrlen(haystack))
```

Here is what i have:

```
  char *mystrstr(char *haystack, char *needle)
{
 if (haystack == needle) { return haystack; }
 int i = 0; int j = 0; 
 while (haystack[i] != '\0') {
   if (j == mystrlen(needle)) {return haystack + (i - mystrlen(needle)); }  
   if (haystack [i] == needle [j]) {
   j++; i++; 
   }   
   else {  j = 0; i++; }

   }
 if (j == mystrlen(needle)) {return haystack + (i - mystrlen(needle)); } 
 return NULL;
}
```

My problem is that when i set j = 0, i dont want to iterate i. But i eventually need to iterate "i" to cause the loop to break. Any suggestions ?

Comment: I suspect 'It doesn't work' isn't the error message you got.

Comment: sorry it was heap errors

Comment: I don't know if you want to look at it, but you can improve the complexity of the function, google for the KMP algorithm. I'd also look at naming your parameters a bit better for `instring` to make it clear what is the needle and what is the haystack. `a` and `b` don't quite do that.

Comment: Oh alrite, thnks i'll check it out

Comment: @Mat I tried making something like the kmp algorithm, here is what i got http://ideone.com/aoANY .... I think there is something wrong with my table array, any suggestions ?

Comment: @Beginnernato, Simple C example can be found [here](http://www-igm.univ-mlv.fr/~lecroq/string/node8.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you don't want to get sophisticated (e.g., Knuth-Morris-Pratt or a Boyer-Moore variant) I think I'd do it by stepping through each possible point in the "haystack", and comparing the N characters of the needle to the next N characters in the haystack. If they're equal, you've found a position.

Edit. In pseudo-code, I'd do something like this:

```
boolean check_pos check_for check_in
    length = getlength(check_for)
    for i = 1 to length
       if (check_for[i] != check_in[i])
            return false
end check_pos

int my_strstr haystack needle
    length = getlength(haystack) - getlength(needle)

    for i = 1 to length
        if (check_pos(needle, haystack+i)
            return i
    return -1
end my_strstr
```

Comment: He doesn't want because he said the running time should be O(mystrlen(needle)*mystrlen(haystack)). Maybe it's easier if he wrote a `mystrncmp` helper function.

Comment: That's my problem, My knowledge so far only let's me compare each character withing the two strings. Is there a way to compare strings, and with like substrings?

Comment: I have a helper function somehwhat like `strcmp` at my disposal, What good will `strcmp` do for me thou? ...

Comment: @Beginnernato: You'd want something like `strcmp`, except that when it treats them as "equal" if it reaches the end of the "needle" string and all the characters up to that point have been equal.

Comment: @ipc: I don't see a problem with complexity. What I've mentioned (ignoring the KMP and BM) is O(N*M).

Comment: @JerryCoffin: I meant "he doesn't want KMP or BM because ...". Sorry for that.

Comment: @JerryCoffin if i want to compare strings, wouldnt i want to split up hackstack into substrings and then use `strcmp` to check if something is equal?

Comment: if i have `char *haystack = "wxyz";`  and  `char *needle = "xy";` wouldnt i need to somehow get "xy" from haystack to use `strcmp` ?

Comment: @JerryCoffin Use a pointer into the haystack, how exactly would i do that ? ... So should i change my approach on how to solve this?

Comment: @JerryCoffin updated an attemped solution ... any suggestions ?

Comment: @JerryCoffin how come you start iterating at one .. shouldnt we start at 0 ?

Comment: @Beginnernato: For this pseudo-code, indices start at 1, but if you have an index that starts at 0, then that's where you'd start.

Answer (score 1):

Loose on details because of home work tag

you want to loop through haystack, i = 0 to i = haystack.length with an inner loop which does j = 0 to j = needle.length.

check for haystack[i + j] = needle[j] if not, you can break out of the inner loop, this is not a match. You then need to work out a way to check if you have looped though all off needle and thus found a match

you also need to make sure you do not get out of bounds (hint, the outer loop end condition)

**EDIT**

Also, don't forget you can access the data like an array

```
int i = 0;
while(haystack[i] != \0){
    // do stuff
    i++
}
```

**EDIT 2**

Another thing you need to remember is that `char*` is not a string, if two variables of type `char*` are the same, it just means they are the same pointer. The check if two C style strings are the same you need to check each character in sequence.

Your outer loop is going need to loop through from the first character `haystack[0]` and would have to stop once it gets to a null character. which will look something like

```
int i = 0;
while(haystack[i] != '\0'){
    // do stuff
    i++;
}
```

you will also need an inner loop, so that for each character of 'haystack' you compare if you can work through needle and get a match. You need to declare this counter variable before the out loop, but set it to zero before each time the inner loop is run so now we have

```
int i = 0;
int j;
while(haystack[i] != \0){
    j = 0;
    while(needle[j] != '\0' && haystack[i + j] != '\0'){
        // noticed that we also check that we are not going out of bounds of haystack
        // do stuff
        j++;
    }
    i++;
}
```

finely, we need to compare each character, so we can simply replace `// do stuff` with a nice check like `if(needle[j] != haystack[i +j]){ // no match yet }`. Now, you are probably going to need to add in a few extra things to help keep track of what is going on, something like a Boolean 'matchFound' which is declared before the outer loop and set to true just before the inner loop.

With this Boolean, it will assume that if after the inner loop, it is still true, a match has been found and the string referred to by 'needle' is in 'haystack and starts at `i`. So after the inner loop, but still in the out loop, we can add a check like `if(mathFound) { return i; }`.

It should be clear that where we check a character of needle with one from haystack, we need to set 'matchFound' to false, where the comment `// no match yet` was. I would also suggest moving the `&& haystack[i + j] != '\0'` into the inner loop, and tweaking so that if has found the null byte for haystack it should set matchFound to false and break from the inner loop.

So, out finale code will be something like

```
int i = 0;
int j;
bool matchFound;
while(haystack[i] != \0){
    j = 0;
    matchFound = true;
    while(needle[j] != '\0'){
        if(haystack[i + j] == '\0' || needle[j] != haystack[i+j]){
            // combined the out of bound check with the comparison
            // note the out of bound check is first, try to think why
            matchFound = false;
            break;
        }
        j++;
    }
    if(matchfound){
        return i;
    }
    // Check first THEN increment i, what happens if we increment i first?
    i++;
}
```

This probably still needs some tweaking to get it work, but it should get you a lot closer to solving you problem

Answer (score 0):

Since this is homework I'll just point you in the right direction and you can figure out the rest.  You're checking for the null terminator on one string but not the other.

Comment: Oh i added the line `(a[i] != '\0' || b[i] != '\0')` to second while loop, but im still getting heap errors ?

Comment: So could this whole test, `(a[i] != '\0' || b[i] != '\0')`,  be true or if `a[0] == '\0'`? Could it be true if `b[0] == '\0'`? If it were true, could it explain the error?

Comment: @Beginnernato: You added a check for b[i] being null but the logical OR you used doesn't fix it.  It will continue scanning past a null terminator.